# Unable to see events in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I saw the notification, "Please upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK by November 15, 2020 to continue getting crash reports". I followed the website and updated the sdk. But did not see the event from the latest app. Old events are still visible.

This is my code:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29
versionCode 173
versionName "2.8.8"
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.1'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0"
```

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

This is my code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent("test_event", bundle);
```

Comment: Analytics events takes some time to fetch values and In your event you haven't passed any value for log event so that event will not be added to your console. And crashlytics reports aren't linked with analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'` in your gradle file. Am I missing something here?

Comment: it was initially present. i removed it. crashes in app is not visible in firebase. is this the reason?